# Remove element from sublist according to another list

Tags: python

I have a list filled with sublist:

```
a = [['12345/0111','57894/0311','45698/2333'],['12345/0600','87456/1234']]
```

Then I have another list:

```
b = ['0111','0600','0311']
```

I would like to delete all elements from list **a** which doesn't contain elements from list **b**.
I thought that it should be like this for the firts element in **b** (in this case 45698/2333 and 87456/1234):

```
for x in a:
    for y in x:
        if b[0] not in y:
            x.remove(y)
```

But it doesn't work even for the first element and I really don't know how to do it for all the elements in **b**.

EDIT: I am sorry I didn't specified that in the output I need to have the same nested list structure.

Comment: what is your expected output.

Comment: looping and removing at the same time !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You most likely want to create a new list from this or generate indices and remove in reverse order. Removing and looping at the same time is never a good idea

Comment: And do you care about it still remaining in a nested list structure or do you want the list flattened?

Comment: I need to have the output still in nested list structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
# create a new list to store values
c = []

for x in a:
   for y in x:
      if str.split(y, '/')[1] in b:
         c.append(y)
```

My Results:

```
a
[['12345/0111', '57894/0311', '45698/2333'], ['12345/0600', '87456/1234']]
b
['0111', '0600', '0311']
c = []
for x in a:
    for y in x:
       if str.split(y, '/')[1] in b:
          c.append(y)

c
['12345/0111', '57894/0311', '12345/0600']
```

EDITED AFTER OP CLARIFICATION:

```
for x in a:
  for y in x:
    if str.split(y, '/')[1] in b:
      x.remove(y)
```

EDITED RESULTS:

```
for x in a:
   for y in x:
     if str.split(y, '/')[1] in b:
       x.remove(y)

a
[['57894/0311', '45698/2333'], ['87456/1234']]
```

Comment: Thank you, It works fine, but I need to have the output still in nested list structure.

Comment: @hejmatt try the edit. This work as you want it to?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying to remove anything that's in b, which doesn't appear to be what you mean.  In any case if you remove the 'not' from either of the following two samples they will give you the ones that are in b.

```
a = [['12345/0111','57894/0311','45698/2333'],['12345/0600','87456/1234']]
b = ['0111','0600','0311']
```

## Not Nested

```
output = []
for l in a:
    for e in l:
        if not any([x in e for x in b]):
            output.append(e)
```

## Nested

```
output = []
for l in a:
    output.append([x for x in l if not any(z in x for z in b)])
```

Comment: This is close, but the result creates a list that has elements that *do not* have those from `b`. Namely, the output is: `['45698/2333', '87456/1234']`

Comment: @Kris isn't that exactly what he asked for

Comment: I think the OP was asking to delete those. (Please clarify, OP?) The fix, in that case, is simple: `...if any([x in e for x in b])...`